# installing GeoDjango--postGIS package broken

Tags: ubuntu, postgis, geodjango, apt, deb

In trying to install GeoDjango as per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/), I'm running into some package dependency issues. I'm using fabric, though I doubt that's relevant. My understanding is that after `fabtools.require.deb.install('binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin python-gdal libgeoip1')` which completes successfully, I should be able to install postGIS, the attempt and output below:

```
[localhost] sudo: DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --quiet --assume-yes postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
[localhost] out: Reading package lists...
[localhost] out: Building dependency tree...
[localhost] out: Reading state information...
[localhost] out: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
[localhost] out: requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
[localhost] out: distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
[localhost] out: or been moved out of Incoming.
[localhost] out: The following information may help to resolve the situation:
[localhost] out: 
[localhost] out: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
[localhost] out:  postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
[localhost] out:                               Recommends: postgis but it is not going to be installed
[localhost] out: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is a deviation from the docs themselves, but using `postgresql-9.3-postgis` as indicated in the docs results in this error:

```
[localhost] sudo: DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --quiet --assume-yes postgresql-9.3-postgis
[localhost] out: Reading package lists...
[localhost] out: Building dependency tree...
[localhost] out: Reading state information...
[localhost] out: Package postgresql-9.3-postgis is not available, but is referred to by another package.
[localhost] out: This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
[localhost] out: is only available from another source
[localhost] out: 
[localhost] out: E: Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis' has no installation candidate
```

which seems even less helpful.

here's a little of the investigating that I've done:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep gdal
gdal-bin                    install
libgdal1h                   install
python-gdal                 install
$ apt show libgdal1h
...
Replaces: libgdal1 (<= 1.10.0-0~), libgdal1-1.6.0 (<= 1.10.0-0~)
...
Breaks: libgdal1 (<= 1.10.0-0~), libgdal1-1.6.0 (<= 1.10.0-0~)
...
```

So it looks like libgdal1h is the issue...or that the postgresql-9.3-postgis package depends on a now obsolete package which is itself replaced by libgdal1h, which, I suppose, was included in one of the first packages installed (like gdal-bin). But I'm not sure where to go from here...

Comment: which Ubuntu version are you using? `lsb_release -a`

Comment: you can try adding the ubuntugis ppa also: `apt-add-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa`. aptitude should take care of dependencies so perhaps you can strike  your `fabtools.require...` line?

Comment: Thanks for the help, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/490073/postgis-dependency-conflicts-ubuntu-14

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue on Ubuntu just with this

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.1 postgis-doc
```

I think you can try doing

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 postgis-doc
```

If you are using postgresql-9.3.

Comment: or for debian try with this: http://www2.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu